# Is Git rm necessary to delete a file from the repo?

Tags: git

If I rename or delete a file using local operating system commands or in an IDE, it seemed like Git was aware of this and I was able to commit the delete just as if I had changed the contents of the file but I may have done this wrong. So my question is, after I delete a file locally, what does Git know about this and do I both have to perform the delete using the IDE *and* do Git rm to get rid of the file from the Git repo?

EDIT: To make more clear the practical situation: Now that I have deleted the file using, in my case, Eclipse (which I would have thought handled the whole git thing transparently) or simply using the Windows command-line, would I still be able to use Git rm? It does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 2):

So I think this is an exercise in understanding the difference between your working directory and the stage in GIT.

Your working directory is what we would think of as your OS directory. You can remove files using OS commands (rm, IDE, etc). GIT is aware of your working directory.

The stage is the "cache" GIT uses to review changes before the final commit. (ex **git status** screen)

With that being said, performing a **git rm** will remove the file from the 'working directory' AND the 'stage'.

Performing an OS 'rm' will only remove from the working directory. This will then require you to perform a 'git add .' to update your stage in preparation for the final commit.

Either way is fine but I am curious if there is a "best practice".

I hope this helps!

Have fun,

-Nick

Answer (score 1):

There are several somewhat-reasonable answers here but no one has addressed a few key points.  I'll put them below the first section marker.

Note that if you want to look at history (i.e., at commits) for a file that may appear and disappear over various commits, you often have to tell `git log` that the file name is a *file* name, and not anything else:

```
git log --all --full-history -- path/to/file.java
```

for instance.  The `--` separates file path names from other arguments, so Git knows not to attempt to turn `path/to/file.java` into a revision specifier.  (A commit that has the effect of deleting the file will be shown, but you won't necessarily know *why*.  Add `--name-status` to the `git log` options to get that information.)

#### You can't remove a file from a Git repository (well, mostly)

The problem is that the repository doesn't *hold* files.  The repository holds *commits*.

Now, it's true that commits hold files, but you also can't—well, *mostly* can't, and generally *should* not—remove commits.  Commits are (mostly) permanent and (entirely) unchangeable.  This means that if the file exists in commits `c0ffee1` and `deadcab`, it exists in those two commits *forever*.

The file may, or may not, exist in *other* commits.  When you make Git check out commit `feedb0b`, will file `x.java` exist?  The (slightly oversimplified simple) answer is: it will if it's in `feedb0b`, and not if it's not.

What `git rm` does is, in part, to remove a file from Git's *index*, which is also called the *staging area*.  When you make the *next* commit, whenever that is and whatever big ugly hash ID it gets then, whatever files are in the index *right now* are the ones that will be in that next commit.

If you remove a file from the *work-tree*, which is where you do your work, you have not affected your index.  Git places this index in between your work-tree and your commits so that it can annoy you. :-)  Well, that's not the real reason, but that's the initial effect: the index acts as an annoyance.  It's why you must constantly keep running `git add`: `git add x.java` copies the file `x.java` from your work-tree, where you can work on it, into the index, so that it can be in the next commit.

Once copied into the index, a file remains in the index until something takes it out.  Using `git rm --cached x.java` will take `x.java` out of the index.  Using `git rm x.java`, i.e., without `--cached`, will take it out of the index *and* remove it from your work-tree.  If it's already gone from your work-tree, both commands do the same thing (remove from index only).

Curiously, if you've already removed it from your work-tree, `git add x.java` will also remove it from your index!  This is an odd meaning for "add".  Note that in modern Git, "add all files" will "add" removed files this way (in Git before 2.x it did not do this by default).

As long as the file is in your index, though, it will also be in the next commit you make.

#### Some notes on untracked files

As soon as any particular file is *not* in your index, it becomes an *untracked* file.  In fact, that's the definition of "untracked file": an untracked file is any file that is not in the index.

Whenever you have untracked files, Git tends to whine at you.  It constantly reminds you: hey, this file is untracked, and that one, and these five!  You can tell Git to stop complaining by listing these untracked files in a `.gitignore` file.  This does two things:

- it shuts up the complaints; and
- it makes Git *not* add those files if you use an "add all files" operation.

It *does not* take the files *out* of the index if they are already there!  An ignore entry for a file is only meaningful if the file is currently untracked.

Since the index *changes* over time, doing `git rm <file>` and committing makes the file untracked, but as soon as you check out one of the older commits that has the file in it, the file comes back into both your index and your work-tree.  The file is now *tracked* again.  So "tracked" or "untracked" is always a question of whether the file is in your index *right now*.  That's not something you can answer once and forever.

This, too, is part of why you can't quite remove a file from the *repository*.  You can remove it from the next *commit*, and anyone who works from that commit will not have the file.  But anyone who works from some *other* commit, might have the file.

(You *can* strip out commits, but it's tricky.)

Comment: The git log did not show the file's deletion -- is that to be expected? And can I do a git rm on a file deleted using the operating system's command (if that file was previously committed)?

Comment: If it's not showing a removal commit, there is no commit where it was there in the "before" (parent) commit and is not there (is `git rm`-ed) in the child. You can also see if it's in your index right now, using the command line `git status` command, or the (verbose and not intended for users) `git ls-files --stage` command that dumps out the semi-raw index contents.

Comment: To actually remove the file from the index, from the command line, use one of the above commands (`git rm <file>`; or `git add` while it's already removed from the work-tree). Note that GUIs often attempt to hide the index from you, since the index *is* annoying. But this is a bad idea, because the index is pretty much everything when it comes to making new commits.

Answer (score 0):

If Git knows about a file, then it will willfully track its deletion.  Simply deleting it from Git will allow it to be resurrected at a later date in time.

If you do not wish for Git to know about a file, then using `git rm --cached` is the appropriate way to remove it from the current stage.  You'll need to couple this with an appropriate `.gitignore` file as well so Git knows never to stage it again.

Comment: How would I see the history of the deleted file and what would I expect to see? When I try: git log --all --full-history fileName.java I do see a list of commits but I do not see a delete. I don't think I did the git rm on the file in the past and it doesn't seem like I can do the rm now because when I do so, it says "did not match any files."

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have deleted the file with rm command, And you want to remove it from GIT repo. Then you have to use git add  ; git commit -m "remove".

But if you will use git rm  command, Then git will remove the file and add it to staging, then next time when you will fire git commit. It will be deleted from repo. So you do not need to add it into staging explicitly if you use this command.